# Azure function not visible in azure portal after upgrading to .net 8 Isolated process model

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-functions, dotnet-isolated

We have recently upgraded our function projects in .net core api app to .net 8 Isolated model. A new timer trigger function has been added in one of the function projects which runs perfectly fine locally but when deployed in portal via azure devops build/release pipeline this new function is not visible. When I publish this project via visual studio, the function does appear and this property`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` is set to 1. However we don't want to run this using packages and set this property as we had to make a number of changes to the project build and release pipeline to accomodate zip deploy. And more than that why shall we switch to zip deploy when using .net 8 Isolated process model. My app settings in azure look like below

[image: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE]
[image]

One of the project files look this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>10</LangVersion>
        <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    -------------
    ------------
```

The new function is not appearing in this list

[image]

Comment: Add the application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` in the `function app=>configuration` and check if it works.

Comment: It’s already set to true in azure portals app settings (can be see in the screenshot above) not sure if you mean if you mean something else

Comment: So when you deploy from VS, it does as a ZIP package and automatically sets `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE: 1`? When you deploy it normally, how do you deploy it then? Are the other functions executing as expected? When the functionapp is deployed, does it mention something on startup? (usually it will output something related to how many functions it has found). Also, can you show the new timer-trigger function?

Answer (score -1):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2078) on GitHub and long story short it could be that .NET 8 is still not fully rolled out in your region, can you try deploying to another region?

If that's your case in the end of the GitHub issue is referenced [another issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2075) where they keep track of the regions that are experiencing problems.

Comment: As I mentioned it works when deployed via visual studio so not an issue with the region apparently.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue. I found my devops pipeline was archiving the bin/Release folder but after the .net 8 change over it needed to be archiving the bin/Release/net8.0 folder. After I changed that the devops pipeline would deploy and I would see the updated functions in Azure.